# iPhone Date Field - Change Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have this field that asks for a date in an iPhone HTML App:

```
<input type="date" name="DepartureDate" id="DepartureDate" placeholder="Date" value="" class="bookingField" />
```

This script:

```
var ddate1 = $('#DepartureDate').val();
alert(ddate1);
```

returns this value: 2012-12-01 (when I select this date of course). Now can I can convert "ddate1" to look like 01/12/2012 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job, demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5jyR/2).

```
$('#DepartureDate').change(function()
{
   var ddate1 = this.value.replace(/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/, '$3/$2/$1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `date()` constructor to initialise your date object :

```
var mydate = new Date("2012-12-01");
```

then output the format you require :

```
var newdate = ("0" + parseInt(mydate.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/' +
              ("0" + (parseInt(mydate.getMonth())+1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
               mydate.getFullYear();
```

Working example -> http://jsfiddle.net/UaEBU/

[Mozilla Docs on Date() are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)